# Using wget to download wordpress article

Tags: c#, wget

I use `wget` to automatically download some websites, blog articles from the web.

I pass some list with links (dynamic and changable one) to `wget` and it should download content from passed links.

I saw a lot of examples, where users successfully downloading offline versions of sites with `wget`.

But all this approaches doesn't work with Wordpress articles or any other sites, where js, css files are hosted on different domain.

For example if the blog url contains wordpress.com, but css, js files are hosted somewhere on wp.com.

Also if I have `http://www.example.com/2013/01/04/article-title/` I need to download only that article and no other, but with attribute 
    `--no-parent` 
wget doesn't download JS and CSS at all because these files are at a higher level than the article path.

Maybe somebody knows any alternative, because `wget` is good for single file downloading, not html?

I tried:

```
wget -Ep --convert-links http://www.example.com/2013/01/04/article-title/
```

This returns only html, without js, css.

**Update:** 
The question: is there any tool, framework for .net, that could download content of websites and has the same functionality as wget.

**Update 2:** 
Ok, i found wget download are better (cleaner and less space requiring). Thanks for link to superuser.com, i found there the solution with wget:

```
wget -H -N -k -p --no-check-certificate -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0a2) Gecko/20110613 Firefox/6.0a2" someurl --content-disposition
```

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Comment: What has this question to do with programming?

Comment: If you are using c#, why are you going back out to the shell with wget?

Comment: Added formatting, paragraphing - please make questions as readable as possible when asking `:)`

Comment: if you have any better tool in .net, let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create mirrors of sites check [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/).

Comment: i think, this is a solution. I will try this ...

Comment: the ui version does, that i want, but console app doesn't download js and css. Maybe someone knows which parameters should i pass ?

Comment: Check the [guide](http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

For online reading, I recommend [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/).

Both have extensions for chrome and addons for firefox.

For storing copies of the articles, using [Evernote](http://evernote.com/) and [Clearly](http://evernote.com/clearly/) gets good results.

Answer (score -1):

You say yourself: "wget is good for single file downloading, not html". Well, it can download single files (or batch files, depending on command line options), it just **won't parse them**. And that seems to be what you want here.

Take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42636/how-to-get-text-of-a-page-using-wget-without-html) suggesting usin `lynx` with the `-dump` option, it has the advantage of being able to be called from within a script or program, while the other answer I gave you can only be used manually.

Comment: I need to make offline version of a site. If no internet connection, that offline version should look like online version, with images, with style and etc.